# Recording time/date PHP form is inserted into SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to order certain uploads by time order arrived (descending), but I'm not sure how I would record the time and date of submission using PHP/SQL. I'm pretty new to this, learning by coming up with projects and working through them as best as I can. Thanks for whatever help you can give me.

EDIT: I understand that the those functions exist, I just have no idea how I would implement them.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) fields that can be automatically updated when the record is updated.

When you specify `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, the current time is inserted in new records. When you specify `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as well, the timestamp is updated when the record is updated. That way, MySQL can automatically log the time for you.

Comment: Would that just log any time the table is updated, or when a new row is inserted?

Comment: It depends. DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, when specified for a TIMESTAMP column, will insert the current timestamp in a new record when it is inserted. ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will update the field of records that are updated. If you specify neither, it is just a regular column with TIMESTAMP as its type, but no automatic inserting or updating is done.

Comment: The page I linked to has the documentation about the TIMESTAMP column, and using these options. There are some restrictions. For one, I believe you can only have one automatic updating TIMESTAMP field per table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using MySQL's [`NOW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function.

Also see MySQL's Date and Time functions : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a column for saving the date and time.

I often use the following two columns:

```
created DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
modified DATETIME DEFAULT NOW()
```

That's all. If you insert a new record, MySQL will automatically update `created` and `modified` to the current date and time.

And if you want to order all uploads by their creation date:

```
SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY created DESC
```

Also see: http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/CREATE-TABLE-examples.html#1_5

Comment: If you're trying to watch your bytes, this costs 2x, the storage, since a DATETIME requires 8 bytes, while a timestamp requires 4.  [reference](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/93-Too-much-information-about-the-MySQL-TIMESTAMP.html)